# Writing Apps for Android with Swift

Tags: android, ios, swift, kotlin

First of all I'm focused on iOS but but I've done ~2 apps for android in Java and it was horrible. I can't explain it why. Was it Java or Android itself but I hate it so much that when now I have to write another app for Android so I'm looking every option for me. This is what I found:

- **Kotlin** - people said this is "Swift for android" but I still stuck with Android libraries.
- **Silver** - "you can use Swift to write code directly against the .NET, Java, Android and Cocoa APIs. And you can also share a lot of non-UI code between platforms." But at this moment I've trouble with download it.

What's your opinion in this matter?

Do you have any experience with those two solutions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no way to write apps for iOS and directly port them to Android.

What you can do is develop the bulk of the app in C++, while having calls to the GUI through JNI java functions.

With that being said, Android isn't scary at all, just face it straight on and you can do it.